# Is there a way to show the Github Network Graph in the CLI?

Tags: git, github

Is there a way to have this display inside the terminal ? :
[image: Network Graph]

I know a similar command but it does not show the same informations,

```
git log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset) %C(white)%s%C(reset) %C(dim white)- %an%C(reset)%C(bold yellow)%d%C(reset)' --all
```

from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057564/pretty-git-branch-graphs) but it does not show the same things as the Network Graph, see

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following will do what you want:
`git log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold cyan)%aD%C(reset) %C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset)%C(bold yellow)%d%C(reset)%n''          %C(white)%s%C(reset) %C(dim white)- %an%C(reset)' --all`